# API to create ARM template programmatically

Tags: java, azure, azure-rm-template

I'm looking for a way to create arm template programmatically behind the screen on drag and drop(form UI), is there any API or SDK which will help me achieving this. Ideally I need an arm visualizer like this http://old.armviz.io/. Any help is highly appreciable.

**Use case:** I'm trying to create an automated ecosystem for all our deployment and monitoring system.

Comment: Visual Studio offers something similar, thou not completely drag and drop. VS code has got arm snippets

Comment: Thanks, I'm using eclipse and planning to design a web based UI.

Comment: @Lambodar It sounds like you want to find some libraries to create a GUI tool based on Web to create arm template via do some drag & drop operations. I think there is not standard answer for you. You can try to use the canvas feature in HTML5 (or combine with other JS libraries like D3) to implement this.